# Semigroups and relations

Tags: abstract-algebra, semigroups

Recall that if $S$ is a semigroup then for $a\in S$ $$Sa = \{sa : s \in S \}\text{,}\;\;\;S^1 a = Sa \cup \{a\}\text{,}$$ $$aS = \{as : s \in S \}\text{,}\;\;\;aS^1 = aS \cup \{a\}\text{.}$$The relation $\mathcal{L}$ on a semigroup $S$ is defined by the rule: $$a\;\mathcal{L}\; b \Leftrightarrow S^1a = S^1b \;\;\;\;\forall \;\;a,b\in S\text{.}$$ Dually, the relation $\mathcal{R}$ is defined on $S$ by:$$a\;\mathcal{R}\; b \Leftrightarrow aS^1 = bS^1 \;\;\;\;\forall \;\;a,b\in S\text{.}$$ Define the relation $\mathcal{H} = \mathcal{L} \cap \mathcal{R}.\;\;\;$ ($\mathcal{L}, \mathcal{R}, \mathcal{H}$ are three of $\textit{Green's relations}$).

Let $S,T$ be semigroups and let $\phi : S \to T$ be a (homo)morphism.

As usual, we apply the map $\phi$ from the right: $a\phi = \phi(a)$

(i) Show that if $a,b \in S$ and $a\;\mathcal{R} \;b$ in $S$ then $a\phi \;\mathcal{R} \;b\phi$ in $T$.

(ii) Assuming the dual result of (i) for $\mathcal{L}$, show that if $a,b \in S$ and $a\;\mathcal{H}\;b$ in $S$ then $a\phi \;\mathcal{H} \;b\phi$ in $T$.

(iii) Show that if $(a,b) \in B$ (the Bicyclic semigroup) then there exists $(c,d)\in B$ such that $$(a,b) \mathcal{R} (c,d) \mathcal{L}(0,0)\text{.}$$

(iv) Suppose now that $\phi :S \to T$ is a homomorphism where $T$ is a commutative semigroup for which $\mathcal{H} = \iota = \{ (a,a) : a \in T \}$. Show that $| \text{im} (\phi) |=1$.

Comment: (iv) is confusing - you state it as a special condition on $T$, but then you say $\{(a,a):a\in S\}$, which is $\mathcal H_S$, not $\mathcal H_T$. Is that what you really mean - $T$ is commutative and $S$ does not any any non-trvial $\mathcal H$ relationships?

Comment: typo, $\iota$ is just the equality relation.

Comment: (iv) still seems wrong, as I've noted in my answer - $S=T$ with $\phi$ the identity would seem to have more than one element in the image, so all you need to do is find a non-trivial such $T$.

Comment: Maybe the problem (iv) is about $S=B$? That would make it related to the previous problem...

Comment: What do you think $\iota$ means then? In the question it just says $\mathcal{H} = \iota$ and for a general set $A$, $\iota$ is the equality relation $\iota = \{ (a,a) : a \in A\} \subseteq A \times A$.

Comment: I think you were right about $\iota$, you just initially wrote it as $\iota_S$ when it should have been $\iota_T$. And I think problem (iv) is about the specific case of $S=B$, the bicyclic semigroup, not a general $S$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Show that $$a\;\mathcal{L}\; b\iff a=b \text { or }\exists s,s'\in S: a=sb, b=s'a$$

Similarly:

$$a\;\mathcal{R}\; b\iff a=b \text { or }\exists s,s'\in S: a=bs, b=as'$$
Note that the existence of $s,s'$ when $a\neq b$ is clear since $a\in S^1a$ and $b\in S^1b$, so if $S^1b=S^1a$ then $a\in S^1b$ and $b\in S^1a$.

Proving that the existence of $s,s'$ is sufficient is the real trick. It isn't actually very hard.

Once you've proved this, the result (i) and the dual follow. Then for (ii) you just use that $$a\;\mathcal H\;b \implies a\;\mathcal R\; b \implies a\phi \;\mathcal R\;b\phi$$

Similarly, $a\;\mathcal H\; b \implies a\phi \;\mathcal L\;b\phi$. So $$a\;\mathcal H\; b \implies a\phi \;\mathcal H\;b\phi$$

For (iii), I'll give the hint that $(c,d)=(a,0)$.

(iv) isn't true. Take $S=T=(\mathbb N,+)$. Then $T$ is commutative, $\mathcal H_T=\iota_T$ and take $\phi=\mathrm{id}_T$.

I'm gonna guess the problem is about $S=B$, not just an arbitrary $S$.

Then first, we note that for commutative $T$, $\mathcal H_T=\mathcal L_T=\mathcal R_T$. In particular, if $T$ is commutative and $\mathcal H_T=\iota_T$ then $\mathcal L_T=\mathcal R_T=\iota_T$.

Then you can show from (iii) and (i) that $(a,b)\phi = (a,0)\phi = (0,0)\phi$, therefore the image of $\phi$ has one element, $(0,0)\phi$.

Comment: $a \; \mathcal{R} \; b \iff aS^1 = bS^1 \iff \exists \; s,t \in S^1$ with $a=bs$ and $b=at \iff a=b$ or $\exists \; s,t \in S$ with $a=bs$ and $b=at$.

Comment: Yes, that's essentially the argument to prove this. The result follows since $\phi(s)$ and $\phi(t)$ then satisfy this condition in $T$.

Comment: There's 2 more parts to the question which I've added: (iii) and (iv). Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry, I don't even know what the Bicyclic semigroup is.

Comment: $B=\mathbb{N}^0 \times\mathbb{N}^0$ with binary operation $$(a,b)(c,d) = (a-b+t , d-c+t)$$ where $t = \text{max} \{b,c \}$.

Comment: When you say $a,b\in B$, it seems like you really mean $(a,b)\in B$. Those are two very different statements.

Comment: typo, yes I meant $(a,b)$